# Is being flanked worse than not being behind cover at all?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I understand that being flanked has a negative impact on defense. But is having the cover on the wrong site (opposite of the enemy) *worse* than standing completely uncovered, or the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check that I interpret the question correctly: I think you are asking whether there is any difference between

Enemy --- Player

and

Enemy --- Player --- Cover

The answer to that is "no", in either case the enemy will have an increased critical hit chance and the cover's defense will not apply.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. So knowing that the enemy _might_ come from a side to which I can't reach useful cover it's still not harmful to cover the "wrong" direction just in case?

Comment: @Zommuter It's not actively harmful, there are better things to do with your turn, like a full-team sprint back to a position which will guarantee cover.

Comment: It's not harmful but, as @Fadeway said, on anything above Easy mode - certainly Classic or higher - knowingly letting yourself be caught out of cover is suicidal.

Comment: As [David B's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129484/88) shows, it _is_ actually harmful, since flanking gives an increased critical hit chance

Comment: @Zommuter test it for yourself, he's wrong. It makes no difference. The video he posted doesn't show an out-of-cover enemy's crit chance either.

Comment: @Fadeway Ah true, I should have asked more clearer "Is being flanked without cover the same as being flanked with cover on the wrong side". Sorry about the confusion on my side